# BASH: Modify column containing also numbers to uppercase

Tags: loops, awk, sed, printf, multiple-columns

I have a big file (~1000x500) with the following (simplified) format:

```
  ABC1    ABC1    0     0     0    0
  a123    a123    0     0     0    0
  a.b1    a.b1    0     0     0    0
```

Some strings in column 1 and column 2 are already in uppercase, while some aren't. There are not only letters in the two first columns but also special characters and numbers.

How can I modify all letters in column 1 and 2 from lowercase to uppercase?

Note: to simplify the example, I put value 0 for the other columns, but in my real file those can be numbers or letters.

---

This is what I tried, however in a big file the script would be too long to write (plus this is not "nice").

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6;
do
    printf "%s%s%s%s%s%7s\n" "${col1^^}" "${col2^^}" "$col3" "$col4" "$col5" "$col6"

done < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{$1 = toupper($1); $2 = toupper($2)}1' input.txt > output.txt
```

This will change the field separators from "whitespace" to a single space.

To maintain the current spacing:

```
perl -pe 's/(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)/ uc($1) . $2 . uc($3) /e'
```

Comment: Both of these options should be significantly faster than a bash "while read" loop

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/(\S+\s+){2}/\U&/' infile
```